# how to make PHPUnit stop intercepting exceptions?

Tags: php, json, api, phpunit, web-api-testing

I am working with a internal framework where every exception is catched by an error handler and returned in a proper JSON error response, suitable for a RESTFul API.

Then I have a suite of tests, which are API tests, that are mainly testing that the API returns the proper JSON responses with the expected error codes.

For every test, the global variables are modified (and then restored) to emulate a different HTTP request. I do it that way to avoid the overload of doing cURL tests (through Guzzle or similar), and cause under the CLI environment, the code does not know the server's url.

```
<?php
// ... example, part of a base ApiTestCase class:

// Override globals (should be backed up by PHPUnit)
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']     = $request->method;
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']       = http_build_query($request->parameters);
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']          = $request->path;
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']        = $request->path . ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? '?' : '') . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']       = time();
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] = microtime(true);
$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']        = '';

// Set headers, cookies and parameters
foreach ($request->headers as $k => $v) {
  $_SERVER['HTTP_' . strtoupper(str_replace('-', '_', trim($k)))] = $v;
}
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']) {
  $GLOBALS['_COOKIE'] = http_parse_cookie($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
} else {
  $GLOBALS['_COOKIE'] = [];
}
$GLOBALS['_REQUEST'] = $request->parameters;

$responseBody = $app->start();

$response->httpCode = http_response_code();
$response->body     = $responseBody ? @json_decode($responseBody) : null;
$response->headers  = headers_list();
```

(I know that changing globals this way is not nice, and the framework should not rely on globals directly, but I have still to deal with legacy code.)

Then here comes the problem: when I try to test JSON error responses: PHPUnit intercepts the thrown exception (before the handler I mentioned in the beginning), so the framework has no chance to convert it to JSON and return the proper response.

I tried to find something in the PHPUnit manual to disable the PHPUnit error handler with no luck.

What could I do in this case? Thanks

Comment: Just to note that most of the code you've quoted looks like it should probably be in a `setup()` function in your phpUnit test class. Also, note that phpUnit has built-in capability for restoring the globals to their pristine state after each test. You may want to make use of that rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: the code is just an example, but that's true that PHPunit make globals backups

Comment: @mjolnic Hi mate, I'm having the exact same issue here. Did you find a suitable resolution?

Comment: The only solution I implemented that works is to not rely on the exception handler to send error responses, but catch exceptions in the top level of your application that will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I implemented that solves my problem is to not delegate the exception handler the responsibility to build and send the API error responses, but catch exceptions in the top level of your application.

In the catch I have an exception-to-error-response converter that takes care of that (or re-throws the exception when convenient), so the errors that are not critical (like the ones producing HTTP 4xx responses) are not popping up in the PHPUnit tests anymore.
My PHPUnit tests are also now able to deal with PSR-7 HTTP Response objects, instead of capturing the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, it sounds like we're not actually talking about catching exceptions here; we're talking about using PHP's `set_error_handler()` to intercept a fatal error before it terminates the program. This will deal with both errors and uncaught exceptions.

One thing you will not be able to do is let those errors and exceptions fall through to your error handler function -- as you've already found out, phpUnit does its own error handling that you can't override (because it's kinda fundamental to how phpUnit works).

What you're going to have to do is tell phpUnit what kind of exception or error you're expecting; your test will then pass or fail according to whether the error occurs. You won't be running the error handler, but in truth, you shouldn't need to; you can test function that separately if you need to. For error conditions, you don't need to see that the error handler produces the right output every time, just that an error occurs that will trigger the handler.

For regular PHP exceptions, you can use phpUnit's `@expectedException` annotation above your test function, like so:

```
/**
 * @expectedException YourExpectedExceptionClass
 */
function testThisWillThrowAnException() {
    ....
}
```

If the PHP code is expected to produce a PHP error (ie an error, not an exception), then you would use the same idea, but phpUnit provides a helper classname for the error: `PHPUnit_Framework_Error`. So your code would look like this:

```
/**
 * @expectedException PHPUnit_Framework_Error
 */
function testThisWillProduceAPHPError() {
    ....
}
```

In either case, your test will pass if the expected error/exception occurs.

You can also test for specific exception messages and codes, in case the exception class itself isn't sufficient information for you to know whether the test has done what you want it to do. See [the phpUnit manual page for annotations](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.expectedException) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I already test those exceptions in the unit tests (which are testing the source code and behavior) and I wouldn't want to duplicate that.

What I am trying to do here is to test the final response: what the clients actually get, which seems not possible in PHPUnit without relying on cURL, which slows down the execution of the tests and don't allow you to mock the source code or data source.

Answer (score 0):

The example above is also correct, mine only provide Exceptions as assertions and gives you knowladge of Exceptions Works.

```
/**
 * @dataProvider fixturesProvider // its just example
 */
public function testDataIsWrong($fixtures)
{
    try
    {
        //Some Code
        $this->fail('Exception');
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($ex,'Exception');
    }
}
```

This also provide  in your code possibility ,that You can Test false or inncorect data and assert it is incorrect.

Comment: The point OP is trying to make is that the exceptions are already caught in his application, and handled there. By the time his API responds, all exceptions are converted to JSON responses, and he wants to check the responses are correct. Adding more exception handling to his tests only treats the symptom, but misses the point entirely and doesn't allow for testing of the JSON response which is the goal.